...from 6.5.0, xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0 is needed to load the Qt xcb platform plugin ERROR trying to run KDE 6 plasma and Wayland on FreeBSD 14.1
I wanted to try to run Wayland + KDE 6 plasma on FreeBSD 14.1. I've created the following tutorial that unfortunately has some errors inside,since the project does not work.
The steps that I have taken are the following :
1 - added user to the wheel and video groups :
sudo pw groupmod wheel video -m marietto

2 - sysrc :
sudo sysrc -f /etc/rc.conf kld_list+="nvidia-modeset nvidia-drm linux linux64 i915kms"

3 - installed the following packages :
==> pkg install --glob "plasma6-*"
==> pkg install --glob "kf6-*"
==> pkg install plasma-wayland-protocols plasma6-xdg-desktop-portal-kde kf6-breeze-icons-6 kde6-devel

4- removed these packages :
pkg remove xdg-desktop-portal-wlr wlrobs grim slurp wlr-which-key wayland-protocols wayfire wf-shell wayfire-plugins-extra

5 - created a startup script called start-kde6 :
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

[ -d $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR ] || mkdir -m 700 -p $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR


export $(dbus-launch)
systemsettings
exit

# [ -d $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR ] || mkdir -m 700 -p $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session ck-launch-session startplasma-wayland


made it executable :


 chmod +x start-kde6



rebooted the machine and logged in as normal user and ran the startup script :


./start-kde6

I see the error below and it does not work :
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, vkkhrdisplay, vnc, xcb, wayland, wayland-egl.

qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: From 6.5.0, xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0 is needed to load the Qt xcb platform plugin.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, vkkhrdisplay, vnc, xcb, wayland, wayland-egl.

I read that this problem can be fixed by installing the package libxcb :
root@marietto:/home/marietto # pkg install libxcb

but in my case it is already installed :
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up to date.
All repositories are up to date.
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
The most recent versions of packages are already installed


The error clearly says that you need xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0.

Install libxcb-cursor-dev package

I'm on FreeBSD 14.1 ; I don't have those packages. Please give a look here : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7Krdtkvsw9/

It may be a bug in detecting the library. There's a recent unanswered post on the FreeBSD forum which claims the library is installed. Consider filing a report on https://bugreports.qt.io
